# Only some elements affected by semi-transparent overlay

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a search overlay for my single page Vue application. On click, an overlay in rendered by Vue.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/cyruscuenca/pen/YdVjaq

I styled the overlay like this:

```
#searchOverlay {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

This is one element that is not being effected by the overlay.

```
#titleBar {
    width: calc(100% - 250px - 30px);
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #17202a;
    color: #D9CDC7;
    position: absolute;
    background: #212f3d;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Check out the attached image to see what the page actually looks like:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI6hZ.png)

This is what the overlay Vue code looks like:

```
<div id="searchBtn" v-on:click="searchOverlay = true">Find or start a chat</div>
<div id="searchOverlay" v-on:click="searchOverlay = false" v-if="searchOverlay == true"></div>
```

This is what the titlebar HTML looks like:

```
<div id="titleBar">{{title}}</div>
```

Comment: I don't think the image really help understanding the issue. Please consider making a minimal example of your problem.

Comment: Please share the relevant HTML structure and CSS because they are related your issue

Comment: @ToanLu I added in the HTML cosponsoring to an element that has the overlay issue. By minimal example, do you mean an HTML/CSS repo?

Comment: @daroldev I updated my question with the HTML. Would you like me to post my whole SPA on GitHub and add a link?

Comment: I hope to see the DOM structure and where do `#titleBar` and `#searchOverlay` locate, as well as which elements have their `z-index` set. Ideally this can be reproduced with a working jsfiddle/codepen example

Comment: @daroldev Updated with a working codepen! Click the search button on the top left to activate the overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codepen is great. So to solve your issue, you can either

1. Move the `#searchOverlay` up two levels, so it is adjacent to `#sidebar` and set `#searchOverlay` to `position: fixed`
   https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PXmBgO

OR

2. Give `#sidebar` a `z-index` higher than `2`, e.g. `z-index: 10`
   https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ebWjXa